# Duplicate Property mapping exception in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using this simple Hibernate Mapping xml to create an entity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class entity-name="FirstTestType">
      <property column="createdOn" name="java.sql.Timestamp" type="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
      <id column="id" name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
         <generator class="identity"/>
      </id>
      <property column="modifiedOn" name="java.sql.Timestamp" type="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
      <property column="testString" length="100" name="java.lang.String" type="java.lang.String"/>
      <property column="testInt" name="int" type="int"/>
      <property column="testBoolean" name="boolean" type="boolean"/>
      <property column="testLong" name="long" type="long"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Though my schema is effectively created when I use SchemaExport

```
    final SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(getHibernateConfigurationForSchema());

    export.create(true, true);
```

When I try to create a  sessionfactory I am getting this exception

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of java.sql.Timestamp found in FirstTestType
    at org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.session.HibernateSessionFactoryProvider.setupSchemaSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactoryProvider.java:78)
    at org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.session.HibernateSessionFactoryProviderTest.testSessionCreation(HibernateSessionFactoryProviderTest.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of java.sql.Timestamp found in FirstTestType
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyDuplication(PersistentClass.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
    at org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.session.HibernateSessionFactoryProvider.setupSchemaSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactoryProvider.java:74)
    ... 11 more
```

Can you help me figure out whats wrong with the Mapping xml ?

Comment: You should not name the properties like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change names in properties;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class entity-name="FirstTestType">
      <property column="createdOn" name="nameCreatedOn" type="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
      <id column="id" name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
         <generator class="identity"/>
      </id>
      <property column="modifiedOn" name="nameModifiedOn" type="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
      <property column="testString" length="100" name="nameTestString" type="java.lang.String"/>
      <property column="testInt" name="nameTestInt" type="int"/>
      <property column="testBoolean" name="nameTestBoolean" type="boolean"/>
      <property column="testLong" name="nameTestLong" type="long"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Your class look like;

```
package basari.util;

public class FirstTestType {

    private Date nameCreatedOn;
    private int nameId;
    private String nameModifiedOn;
    private String nameTestString;
    private int nameTestInt;
    private Boolean nameTestBoolean;
    private Long nameTestLong;

    public FirstTestType(){

    }

    public Date getNameCreatedOn() {
        return nameCreatedOn;
    }
    public void setNameCreatedOn(Date nameCreatedOn) {
        this.nameCreatedOn = nameCreatedOn;
    }
    public int getNameId() {
        return nameId;
    }
    public void setNameId(int nameId) {
        this.nameId = nameId;
    }
    public String getNameModifiedOn() {
        return nameModifiedOn;
    }
    public void setNameModifiedOn(String nameModifiedOn) {
        this.nameModifiedOn = nameModifiedOn;
    }
    public String getNameTestString() {
        return nameTestString;
    }
    public void setNameTestString(String nameTestString) {
        this.nameTestString = nameTestString;
    }
    public int getNameTestInt() {
        return nameTestInt;
    }
    public void setNameTestInt(int nameTestInt) {
        this.nameTestInt = nameTestInt;
    }
    public Boolean getNameTestBoolean() {
        return nameTestBoolean;
    }
    public void setNameTestBoolean(Boolean nameTestBoolean) {
        this.nameTestBoolean = nameTestBoolean;
    }
    public Long getNameTestLong() {
        return nameTestLong;
    }
    public void setNameTestLong(Long nameTestLong) {
        this.nameTestLong = nameTestLong;
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the column name and the property name cannot be same ? if yes what could be the reason and if no what is the significance difference between column and name attributes ? TIA

Comment: columnName is looking hibernate.hbm.xml file. PropertyName is mapping for controller as @RequestParam

Comment: I am not using Spring or anything so @RequestParam has no significance . Can you please explain with more hibernate like explanation ?

Comment: Okay i will explain like just a java project. lets think that hibernate mapping is your db example. When you make this hibernate mapping you have to make class which includes all column names as a private variable in Class (with getter and setter). That property name is class variable name.

Comment: so simply put hibernate needs us to specify separate property and column names. I realized on a second run my mistake with the property naming.. they look like types. I fixed that and sorted out the session creation issue